# Deserialize multiple Json objects to their respective types

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a Json of different types posted to my service.

```
var postedJson = [
    { "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe" },
    { "fruit":"apple", "Available":"false" },
    { "length":100, "width":60, "height":30 },
    { "firstName":"Shivang", "lastName":"Mittal" }
]
```

I have same type of models on service side, how to create a generic method to recieve the data and then deserialize it based on their type.

Right now i am doing it like below

```
public void SaveData(MasterModel data)

public class MasterModel 
{
    public PersonInfo Person{get; set;}
    public DimensionInfo Dimension{get; set;}
}
```

I want to make this SaveData generic so that anytime someone call the service, it automatically match the corresponding types and and bind with model.
Is there any good way to do that

Comment: Is it possible to you to change the current JSON structure ?

Comment: @OrelEraki : Yes, I can do that

Comment: I would try `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` .  `var listOfDicts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);`

Comment: @EZI : Binding to the models is important to push the data to Elasticsearch based on their type and there are certain validations also on models

Answer (score 2):

Few things are first advised.

1. Changing the JSON format to more parsable. Example: http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/71f495
2. Capital letters are also a good idea, due the fact those properties are converted to strongly types properties.

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hGoidD)

**Main**

```
string json = "[  {    \"Name\": {      \"FirstName\":\"John\",      \"LastName\":\"Doe\"    },    \"Fruit\": {      \"Fruit\":\"apple\",      \"Available\":\"false\"    },    \"Dimensions\": {      \"Length\": 100,      \"Width\": 60,      \"Height\": 30    }  }  , {    \"Name\": {      \"firstName\":\"Shivang\",      \"lastName\":\"Mittal\"    },    \"Fruit\": {      \"Fruit\":\"orange\",      \"Available\":\"true\"    },    \"Dimensions\": {      \"Length\": 120,      \"Width\": 40,      \"Height\": 10    }  }]";

var model = new Model();
// Here is the magic happening, thanks to `Newtonsoft.Json`
model.Peoples = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
```

**Entities**

```
public class Model
{
    public List<Person> Peoples { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public Name Name { get; set; }
    public Fruit Fruit { get; set; }
    public Dimensions Dimensions { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }   
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Fruit
{
    public string Type { get; set; }    
    public bool Available { get; set; }
}

public class Dimensions
{
    public int Length { get; set; } 
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The call will still not be generic. I need to add the new types in "public class Person" everytime any new type comes.